Построение рабочего графика
Стоит задача: создать программу, которая скриптом/веб-приложением или др создает рабочий график (можно даже в Excel таблице, к примеру на opencsv)
Всего график будет состоять на 50-100 человек и у каждого человека на каждый день разное время в которое он работает (например, понедельник - 12:00-21:00, вторник - 13:00-22:00), но норма - 9 часов у всех. Так же есть ночные и дежурные смены, после ночной идет выходной. Суббота и воскресенье выходные у всех, но дежурные с 12-ти часовой сменой все равно есть. Это все необходимо чтобы покрыть график работы 24/7. И таких условий очень много. Поэтому даже не понимаю с чего начать и какие библиотеки использовать и в каком виде вообще проще и лучше написать программу
Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать, какие библиотеки использовать, какие шаги мне предстоят?

Большого слона надо есть по частям.  Для начала следует уточнить существенные требования к расписанию: к примеру, вы пишете что норма -- 9 часов на человека и сразу же -- что есть 12-часовые дежурные смены на выходных, то есть у дежурных явно должны возникать выходные по будним дням.  С ежедневным часовым сдвигом времени смен не понятно, какие смены будут являться ночными и т.д.  И главное -- при чем здесь собственно Java, это чисто алгоритмическая задача.

См. Как реализовать оптимальную расстановку расписания занятий в уч. заведении?, или изучайте статьи типа "Алгоритмы и методы решения задач составления расписаний ..." (PDF)
